# Future investment: Erlang vs. Scala

Tags: scala, concurrency, erlang

since concurrent programming becomes constantly more important, I was wondering
what you think about Erlang vs. Scala in that respect. It seems to me that Scala
has a larger user base and potentially a brighter future than Erlang. Furthermore,
Scala is kind of java.

I know these questions are alway a bit subjective, but what would be the better
future investment: Erlang or Scala. Or even another language?

Comment: the fact that Scala integrates seamlessly with Java would be the reason to go with Scala.

Comment: se also https://github.com/boundary/scalang 
Scalang is a scala wrapper that makes it easy to write services that interface with erlang

Answer (score 90, accepted):

Erlang has been designed for concurrent, fault-tolerant communication systems. You can easily write servers that handle large number of network connections and (thanks to one garbage collector per Erlang process) the servers can retain soft real-time characteristics (i.e., the whole server is not paused until GC finishes). You can also hot-swap Erlang code, distribute it across several nodes, etc. That's why (arguably) the most-scalable XMPP server (ejabberd) is written in Erlang. Yaws (a web server) is another example where Erlang excels, see: http://www.sics.se/~joe/apachevsyaws.html. Riak/Couch are examples of NoSQL DB build with Erlang. These are the problems where Erlang is a great choice.

But Erlang VM is not as fast as JVM in terms of raw computations, so as soon as you need to do something computationally intensive (e.g. financial modeling) JVM will be your preferred platform. Moreover, Erlang's concurrency model (actors) is baked in the language. If that doesn't fit the problem you're trying to solve, then you won't be happy with Erlang.

Scala is more 'general' language in a sense that concurrency, horizontal scalability, or fault-tolerance is not part of the language. It is solved at the level of libraries (that's why there are at least 3 implementations of actors in Scala). The good thing is that you can pick concurrency model that fits your domain. For example if you need software transactional memory (STM), just pick Akka and you're good to go (http://akka.io/).

Plus there is the whole argument that with Scala you can leverage your "JVM investments" and multitude of JVM libs.

You didn't give any info on what kind of software you want to write with either of those languages so it's hard to give you a definitive answer. Having said that, given all the above, Scala may be "safer" investment than Erlang (not bashing Erlang/OTP at all, it's a fine language/platform).

BTW. If a single-machine concurrency is important to you Clojure (http://clojure.org/) should not be overlooked (also JVM language).

UPDATE1: If you like what Erlang offers but not its syntax, take a look at [elixir-lang.org](http://elixir-lang.org)

UPDATE2: STM has been removed from Akka - now you have a choice (mix/match) between actors (untyped or typed) and streams.

Comment: So the question really is Java Libraries + Processing Speed > Erlang Fault Tolerance + Massive Concurrency? Love the static typing, and you can't been that is has an actual "string" type… You would think Armstrong would have considered a string type before maps? And obviously the name-spacing helps. So in conclusion, there is a lot wrong in Erlang that is solved in Scala, but Scala gives you more that enough rope to hang yourself.

Comment: @expelledboy 'there is a lot wrong in Erlang' sounds a bit harsh, but yes, there are things in Erlang that can be improved (can be said about any PL). If you look at elixir-lang.org that's exactly what they are trying to do (for their definition of 'better').

Answer (score 38):

**It doesn't matter** Just pick one and stick with it for a while.  Learn some stuff, make some cool things and either keep going with that language or move on to another one.

With respect to learning concurrent programming, either will be fine.  The key here is that you will be learning something new and unless there's a job opening that you are trying to get hired for that uses Erlang specifically, it really doesn't matter.  Plus, even if that opening did require Erlang, you would still likely have a good chance if you knew Scala really well.

Just think, all of the time you have spent trying to pick a new language could have been better spent if you just picked one and already started learning it by now.

Comment: ha, yeah.  I don't know.  Although having some side projects in any language can help you get a job, so I guess in a round about way, Scala can help you get a job :P

Comment: I just got my first Erlang job, so... it doesn't really matter. If you're a good programmer, you're good in just about every language. Learn what you like! That said there are *probably* more Scala jobs due to the Java integration. Look up functionaljobs.com, for instance. Most jobs are Scala/Erlang related.

Comment: This is a great answer - start somewhere and take it from there!

Answer (score 5):

Both languages, at the core, are not that hard to learn, and also to learn the concurrency features they provide. In fact, Scala actors are influenced by Erlang actors. I would go to both of them, take your time looking at their construct, do some tests in concurrency problems, etc.

If you know Java, Scala will be more natural, as Erlang is more like prolog. If, on the contrary, you're more oriented towards mathematical or logical type of languages, start with Erlang.

Comment: Scala is not hard to learn?
Please.
Erlang is like 10 keywords with a glue.
Scala has 13 different meanings of "_" depending on context.
Erlang is *much* easier language to learn.

Comment: Well, it may be. Learning Scala from Java is not that dramatic. Of course, being completely idiomatic is another thing, but still, learning OTP is not that easy either. The OP is speaking about learning a language.

Comment: I am java developer and I spend days just to write a single line of scala code. But I like it, I learn a lot when write that line ( to remove intermediate variable)