# Concurrency model: Erlang, Elixir, and Scala

Tags: scala, concurrency, erlang, elixir, actor

What is the difference between the **concurrency models** of Erlang, Elixir, and Scala?

Comment: Sorry, but this question shows zero effort in doing any research yourself. There are enough websites explaining each concurrency model. If you have a concrete question then ask that one instead.

Comment: Even without leaving Stackoverflow, I'm pretty sure you can find answers regarding Erlang vs Scala

Comment: https://sm-dev.edutone.net/Java/Seven%20Concurrency%20Models%20in%20Seven%20Weeks.pdf

Comment: I get what you're asking and why you're asking it -- this is a *very* important subject to understand -- but most people on SO will probably not find this to be a good fit for SO's Q/A style. I answered this with a list of references because its just too hard to answer with zero prior knowledge assumed on the part of the asker. This will *probably* work best if I just create a page external to SO with some general conceptual information and a list of references.

Comment: Incidentally, this is relevant in important ways, but not a strong enough source of general information to put down as a canonical reference below, imo: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46747592/elixir-processes-and-no-shared-heap-memory/46748169#46748169

Answer (score 8):

This is way too hard to answer from a point of zero prior knowledge. I think the most valuable way to even approach it (because this sort of thing gets asked all the time in a most unhelpful sort of way) is to include some links to reference information about these -- and then close the question.

(If this is such a bad idea in the minds of other SO users that you think we should delete this entirely I'll create a resource page external to SO to use as a future reference-to-references.)

- [Erlang Process vs Java Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32294367/erlang-process-vs-java-thread)
- [Is Scala's actors similar to Go's coroutines?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22621514/is-scalas-actors-similar-to-gos-coroutines)
- [Future investment: Erlang vs. Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6820195/future-investment-erlang-vs-scala)
- [Seven Concurrency Models in Seven Weeks](https://pragprog.com/book/pb7con/seven-concurrency-models-in-seven-weeks)
- [Qt Concurrent](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtconcurrent-index.html) (Qt documentation that explains a bit about how the underlying madness of shared memory concurrency is tamed somewhat within that framework)
- [An Introduction to Asynchronous Programming and Twisted](http://krondo.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/08/twisted-intro.pdf)
- [Parallelism](https://wiki.haskell.org/Parallelism) and [Concurrency](https://wiki.haskell.org/Concurrency) (Haskell Wiki)
- [Why Events are a Bad Idea](https://www.usenix.org/legacy/events/hotos03/tech/full_papers/vonbehren/vonbehren_html/) (USENIX paper -- good foundational information)
- [Wikipedia article on Concurrency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concurrency_(computer_science))
- [Why Microservices?](https://dzone.com/articles/microservices-basics) (conceptually relevant, particularly since Erlang and other "actor systems" usually fit the conceptual definition of being swarms of microservices, whether distributed or not)
- [Concurrency: Time is of the Essence](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/sicp/book/node66.html) (SICP -- *FYI: This entire text is probably one of the most important things you can read as a programmer*)

Comment: While I'm very grateful for the recommendation for "Seven Concurrency Models", I would prefer that SO answers do not include links to pirated copies of copyright material. I've changed it to a link to the book's page on the publisher's website.

Comment: @PaulButcher Gotcha. I was not aware that was a pirate link. Thanks for fixing it.